# Setting the content inset of a UICollectionView inside of a UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController which contains UICollectionViewControllers who's collectionView'scontentInset that need to be adjusted. For various UI-layout reasons, I only need the contentInset on these UICollectionViewControllers when they appear in a UIPageViewController. Below is my attempt to adjust the contentInset for the collectionView.

```
   self.viewControllers = [ ViewControllerA(), ViewControllerB(), ViewControllerC()]
     for viewController in viewControllers {
        if let vc = viewController as? UICollectionViewController, collectionView = vc.collectionView {
            collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: bottomContentInset(), right: 0)
        }
    }
```

The problem that I am encountering is that only the first view controller(on the first page) gets the contentInsetadjusted, is there a better way of doing this

Comment: have you tried subclassing and setting those properties as a default?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you solved this, but this may've been occurring because only the visible collection view's cells (in `ViewControllerA`) were dequeued. The collection views' cells in your other VCs possibly hadn't yet been dequeued, or it's possible the other VCs themselves hadn't yet been initialized (not sure how you instantiate the VCs). I would either use the `UIPageViewController`'s delegate methods to set each collection view's `contentInset` property, or try it in the `viewWillAppear:` method of each VC.